# How to change images from a ViewPager in a determined time?

Tags: android, image, time, viewpage

I made a slide banner that displays 3 images in Android with ViewPager, but now I need that it changes every 5 seconds between the 3 images.

I tried with a thread but I don't know how to make the change when I reach the 5 seconds.

Can anyone help me please?

This is my main

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPagerMain);
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(MainActivity.this,imagesArray);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    TextView tvEventos = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.eventos);
    tvEventos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EventActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    TextView tvPromociones = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.promociones);
    tvPromociones.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EventActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    TextView tvDirectory = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.directorio);
    tvDirectory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DirectoryActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    TextView tvPinatas = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pinatas);
    tvPinatas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CumpleaniosActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    TextView tvBebes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bebes);
    tvBebes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BebesActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

this is my ViewPagerAdapter

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();


    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPagerMain);
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(MainActivity.this,imagesArray);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    TextView tvEventos = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.eventos);
    tvEventos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EventActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    TextView tvPromociones = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.promociones);
    tvPromociones.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EventActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    TextView tvDirectory = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.directorio);
    tvDirectory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DirectoryActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    TextView tvPinatas = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pinatas);
    tvPinatas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CumpleaniosActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    TextView tvBebes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bebes);
    tvBebes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BebesActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

I dont know where to create the Thread and how to make the change of the position.

Comment: Hey add some source code!

Answer (score 0):

Use `Handler#postDelayed(Runnable task, long delayInMillis)`:

```
int count = 0;
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable task = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (count == 3) return;

        pager.setCurrentItem(count);
        count++;
        handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);   
    }
}
handler.postDelayed(task, 5000);
```

Comment: this should be on the Main or the ViewPagerAdapter? (I already include the code above)

Comment: @Melfo In the `main` but please make sure you read the documentation for Handler [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `ViewPager` is named `pager`, you can use code like this to "advance" the image every time your timer fires:

```
int current = pager.getCurrentItem();
int size = pager.getAdapter().getCount();

if (current < (size - 1)) {
    pager.setCurrentItem(current + 1, true);
} else {
    pager.setCurrentItem(0, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your code logic? Explain a little bit and show the code. This here is done with Handle and Timer, executed every 5s(5000ms)

Define variable for pages count:

`pagesCount = 0;`

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
                    final Runnable task = new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            if(pagesCount == 3){
                               pagesCount = 0;
                            }else{
                               pagesCount++;
                            }
                            ViewPager.setCurrentItem(pagesCount);
                        }
                    };

                timer = new Timer(); 
                timer .schedule(new TimerTask() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        handler.post(task);
                    }
                }, 0, 5000);
```

Comment: I already edit the post and put my code, I will really appreciate your help